# What is the criteria that maze is valid

Tags: breadth-first-search

I know that valid maze needs to have one entry point and one exit point. 
bfs traverse per level from level 0 , level 1 and so on and then we marked true if it's already visited till the queue is empty.
Assuming '#' represents a wall and '.' represents a path how do I tell to computer that the maze is connected or not ? 
for example this one is connected

# . #

# . #

# . #

i've been surfing online looking for explanation but it's just not enough,

Comment: This is very broad. Can you provide what you have done so far and a specific question about what is not working? Please refer to
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is what BFS or other path-finding algorithms do. 
It searches for a path - a continuous connected non-wall nodes, `.`  in the example you gave.
To be able to do so, the algorithm need to know who are the neighbors of each node. 
This information is typically provided to the algorithm by an adjacency matrix, or a neighbors list.